# WriteableBitmap and scaling factor

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, uwp, winrt-xaml

because of image flickering I've used WriteableBitmap. I have images with 3 scaling factors. But **GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync** always reads the image with highest scaling factor and images are too big on mobile device.
Here is my code:

```
private async Task<WriteableBitmap> CreateBitmapImage(Uri uri)
    {
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
        BitmapImage bitmapImage;
        WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap;
        using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
            writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage.PixelHeight, bitmapImage.PixelWidth);
            fileStream.Seek(0);
            await writeableBitmap.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
        }
        return writeableBitmap;
    }
```

I use BitmapImage because WriteableBitmap needs pixel height and width as input parameters in constructor. Uri is e.g.: ms-appx:///Images/contact.png

Comment: Why not have 3 image files with different sizes, like contactSmall.png, contactMedium.png and contactLarge.png? Besides that, it's unclear why a WriteableBitmap returned from your method would avoid any flickering that a BitmapImage would produce.

Comment: I have contact.scale-100.png, contact.scale-200.png, contact.scale-400.png. If I directly bind uri to Imagesource, the system knows, which scaling factor to choose, but it flickers always, when I change the image. BitmapImage/WriteableBitmap resolved flickering, but it always take image with highest scale factor.

Comment: It will work. But I don't want to do this manually. System should decide, which image to use according to current sceen resolution etc. If I do: 'ImageSource="/Images/contant.png"', it uses image, which is suitable.

Comment: Strange. According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965325.aspx), automatic scaling should also work with GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync.

Comment: I don't know, why it is not working. It should be.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it this way:

```
<Image Grid.Column="0" x:Name="StatusImage" Margin="0,8,12,8" Source="{x:Bind ImageStatusUri, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ImageOpened">
                            <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Source" Value="{Binding ElementName=StatusImage, Path=Source}" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=CopyOfStatusImage}"/>
                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </Image>
<Image Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,8,12,8" x:Name="CopyOfStatusImage"/>
```

So I don't need to use WriteableBitmap and GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync